# Is $0$ the root of the equation $\frac{x^2}{ x}= 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to understand if I understand the concept of equation correctly. For this I want to know if $0$ is the root of the equation $\frac{x^2}{x} = 0$. If we simplify the equation then we can get equation $x = 0$ and then we have solution $0$. But if we replace $x$ by $0$ in the original equation then we get expression $\frac{0^2}{0} = 0$ which doesn't make sense. I'm interested in your opinion.

Comment: The equation has no solution since the left side is $x$ for $x \ne 0$ , but undefined for $x=0$

Comment: Thank you @Peter

Comment: See posts like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198313/a-thorough-explanation-on-why-division-by-zero-is-undefined) concerning division by zero.

Comment: Also, an equation can have solutions, a function roots. An equation has no root.

Comment: The equations $x^2/x=a$ and $x=a$ have different definitions. The former is not defined when $x=0$

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the function $f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{x^2}{x}&x\neq 0\\42&x=0\end{cases}$ (*I just picked 42 as an example, no real mathematical meaning to the number 42... I just needed the domain to be all real numbers*) has a [*removable discontinuity*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html) at $x=0$.  That is likely what you are intuitively trying to get at in attempting to simplify the fraction and cancel an $x$ from top and bottom.  The punchline is that officially the original function you refer to is not defined for $x=0$, that's outside the domain

Comment: but your function does have the limit as $x\to 0$ of zero.

Comment: @JMoravitz 42 actually seems to have a meaning… https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_is_42

Comment: @insipidintegrator yes, that was the inside joke... it didn't need to be said aloud.  We just commonly use $42$ when we have a choice available to make and the number used doesn't actually matter to prove the point we were trying to make...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this system is indeterminate and there is no solution for $x=0$. The key point in this question is to figure out how simplifying a system can often hide certain properties of it, or how simplifications can be incorrectly made by violating certain mathematical conditions.

Take for instance, the equation you have:
$$\frac{x^2}{x} = 0$$

All mathematical systems are dependent on how they are simplified. In this form, there can be no solution, because have the form $\frac{0^2}{0}$ which is indefinite.

The problem with the method of simply bringing the denominator over to the right-hand side (RHS) is that it simplifies the equation and loses the importance of the fraction representation. The indefinite form specifically has a condition that if it is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$, then it cannot be simplified by shifting the denominator to the opposite side (LHS or RHS). Thus, when simplifying the system, you missed this important condition.

Bottom line, canceling 2 terms on the RHS and LHS require the term to be divided across both sides, but this yields an indefinite answer if the division creates an indeterminate/indefinite form.

Here's a famous example of a proof that goes wrong because of the incorrect application of the above condition:
$$
\begin{align}
Let, \ a & = b \\
a^2 & = ab \\
a^2 + a^2 & = a^2 + ab \\
2a^2 & = a^2 + ab \\
2a^2 - 2ab & = a^2 + ab - 2ab \\
2(a^2 - ab) & = a^2 - ab \\
2 & = 1
\end{align}
$$

The error lies in the last step, since you cannot cancel out the term $a^2-ab$ from LHS & the RHS. The reason is because when you cancel out the term, you are essentially dividing the term across both sides. However, you know that $a^2 - ab = 0$ from the assumption $a=b$, meaning that your equation becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
2\left[\frac{a^2-ab}{a^2-ab}\right] & = \left[\frac{a^2-ab}{a^2-ab}\right] \\
2\left[\frac{0}{0}\right] & = \left[\frac{0}{0}\right]
\end{align}
$$
Which is an indeterminate/indefinite form, rendering the proof incorrect. The same logic extends to your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, the equation has no solutions. The problem comes from the step of simplifying the equation. In this step you are dividing by $x$, but in that case you are dividing by $0$, which is not allowed. If you assume that $x\not=0$, you can simplify and get $x=0$, which is a contradiction. So the equation has no solutions