# Is "Undefined = Undefined" (e.g. $\frac{1}{0}=\frac{2}{0}$) true/false/undefined/something else?

Tags: logic

Another example: Define $f:\mathbb R^+_0 \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=\sqrt x$.

Is the statement $f^\prime (0) = \frac{0.5}{\sqrt 0}$ true/false/undefined/something else?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198313/a-thorough-explanation-on-why-division-by-zero-is-undefined) - division by zero is always undefined. Of course, $\sqrt{0}=0$.

Comment: It makes no sense to compare undefined objects. "$A=B$" is meaningless , if $A$ and $B$ are not both defined.

Comment: depends on the use case. the consensus is that the comparison between undefined and anything else is meaningless

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I think you misunderstand. My question is not whether $\frac{1}{0}$, $\frac{2}{0}$, and $\frac{0.5}{\sqrt 0}$ are undefined (I agree they are). My question is about whether $\frac{1}{0}=\frac{2}{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: Isn't this the same? Both "terms" are undefined, as you say yourself. How can then  the "equality" be meaningful? We don't even know what to compare with an equal sign. In the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200919/true-or-false-or-not-defined-statements?noredirect=1&lq=1) they discuss $\frac{1}{0}=\frac{1}{1}$, but your case has this problem even "more".

Comment: Well-formed mathematical expressions refer to a value "out there" (e.g., $\frac{1}{2}$ refers to the (unique) real number that gives 1 if you multiply it by 2). Not every string of characters is meaningful in that sense. This holds for expressions such as "$1/0$" or "$7+-*/(5$". Since such expressions are meaningless, comparing them for equality does not make any sense ("*not even* undefined"). This is like asking "Is it colder outside than at night?"